# Run multiple Bokeh servers

Tags: python, bokeh

I have multiple Python scripts to create Bokeh apps on different ports.

Currently, I start each server individually from command line using `bokeh serve`

What is the easiest way to run  multiple Bokeh servers on different ports ideally by running a single Python script?

Is it possible to set the permitted clients individually for each server?

Comment: What do you mean by "permitted clients"?

Comment: Who can access the server- currently controlled by setting the BOKEH_ALLOW_WS_ORIGIN variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bash solution would be simpler, but if you really need a Python one then here it is:

```
import shlex
from multiprocessing import Process

from bokeh.command.bootstrap import main

argss = ['--port 57878 --allow-websocket-origin localhost:57878 test.py',
         '--port 58989 --allow-websocket-origin localhost:58989 test.py']

processes = [Process(target=main, args=(['python', 'serve'] + shlex.split(args),)) for args in argss]
for p in processes:
    p.start()
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Just adapt the `argss` list to your needs.

Note that `bokeh.command.boostrap` is not a public API - it may easily change in any future version. To prevent breakage, you can use the `subprocess` module to instead start proper `bokeh serve` commands.